# .net 8 - dontet-ef doesn't work in Ubuntu

Tags: .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core, dotnet-sdk

I installed `dotnet-sdk` using snap in `Ubuntu v.22.04`. When I run `dotnet --info` here are the details:

```
    dotnet --info
.NET SDK:
 Version:           8.0.100
 Commit:            57efcf1350
 Workload version:  8.0.100-manifests.6c33ef20

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     ubuntu
 OS Version:  22.04
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         linux-x64
 Base Path:   /snap/dotnet-sdk/233/sdk/8.0.100/

.NET workloads installed:
 Workload version: 8.0.100-manifests.6c33ef20
There are no installed workloads to display.

Host:
  Version:      8.0.0
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       5535e31a71

.NET SDKs installed:
  8.0.100 [/snap/dotnet-sdk/233/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 8.0.0 [/snap/dotnet-sdk/233/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 8.0.0 [/snap/dotnet-sdk/233/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Other architectures found:
  None

Environment variables:
  DOTNET_ROOT       [/snap/dotnet-sdk/current]
```

the latest `dotnet-sdk` isn't available in ubuntu's feed; therefore, I had to install it using snap. I also have the `DOTNET_ROOT` env. variable setup because this is a known issue and the solution is outlined in [this post](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/34590).

After installing `dotnet-ef` by running `dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef`, when I run `dotnet ef`, I get the following exception:

```
You must install or update .NET to run this application.

App: /home/akhakpouri_linux/.dotnet/tools/dotnet-ef
Architecture: x64
Framework: 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '8.0.1' (x64)
.NET location: /snap/dotnet-sdk/233

The following frameworks were found:
  8.0.0 at [/snap/dotnet-sdk/233/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Learn more:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed
```

I've exhausted all resources and not sure what else to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, if you're installing `dotnet-sdk-8.0.xx` using snap, you'll run into this issue no matter what you've set the `DOTNET_ROOT` to. The problem is that snap installs the sdk in `/snap/dotnet-sdk` instead of `$home/.dotnet/sdk`.

The only way I've been able to get both `.net-sdk` and `dotnet-ef` to work is to perform the followings:

- remove `dotnet-sdk` by `snap remove dotnet-sdk`
- remove `.dotnet` directory by `rm ~/.dotnet`
- remove `rm /snap/dotnet` or `/rm /snap/dotnet-sdk` if they exist.

You want to install the `dotnet-sdk` using script installation mentioned on microsfot's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-scripted-manual#scripted-install). After running through the installation, make sure to follow the steps in **Set environment variables system-wide** [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-scripted-manual#set-environment-variables-system-wide).

Comment: I understand that this answer is a workaround, but it does the job. Until someone can help me with the snap installation, I'm going to continue using msft's feed instead.